# Custom showsCameraControls for UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to add two extra buttons to my UIImagePickerController. I saw that done in an app: 
[camwow](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/camwow-free-photo-booth-effects/id418368641?mt=8) but I couldn't find the documentation to do that. I have a view overlay over the UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera but at the moment touches on the buttons from the view overlay propagate to the camera controller which focuses.

Comment: Are you sure camwow uses stock image picker? Maybe they implemented their own.