# Change default option of UIimagePickerController

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

after taking a picture it is displying Retake,Preview and Use button.I need to change Use button as Save button.Is it possible?.

```
UIImagePickerController * imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

Comment: No, it is not possible...

Comment: Check this, kinda similar problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987486/custom-showscameracontrols-for-uiimagepickercontrollersourcetypecamera